# Two equal jQuery scripts with different behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an script that when click a button do many things and also rename some elements, so at first I use first script and I see sometimes work, sometimes not, so change it to second script and all time worked perfectly, but there is a question. is this two scripts do same? what is the difference, rather than all of my script I just replace first one with second one.

This is first script

```
$(CloneTarget).find(':input[name="' + MainName + '"]').attr('name', NewSelectName);
```

And second one:

```
$(CloneTarget).find(':input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('name') == MainName) {
        $(this).attr('name', NewSelectName);
    }
});
```

Where is the problem with first one?

**Edit**

Also I use this:

```
    $(CloneTarget).find(':input[id="' + MainId + '"]').attr('id', NewSelectId);
```

And every thing worked fine I am really confused here, I must mention `MainName` and `MainId` are so similar like: `MainName = Model.Phones[0]` and `MainId = Model_Phones[0]` is the difference is about `.` character or any other things?

Comment: what "does not work" in the first script?

Comment: Can you give the HTML part as well, just to be clear.

Comment: @Saeid, the `.` character may be mistaken for the start of a class selector, however it doesn't seem to be the case as of jQuery 1.7. Are you using an earlier version of the library?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes. I use jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. Your second code snippet performs a string comparison between the element's `name` attribute and the value of `MainName`. The first one directly injects the value of `MainName` into an [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector.

Therefore, the first snippet will fail if `MainName` happens to contain:

- a single quote character `'`,
- a double quote character `"`,
- a character that requires escaping in selectors, such as `[` or `\`.

Comment: That's awesome, I think my `MainName` is similar of your description, but I use it with Id without any problem, I update question

Comment: But you aren't supposed to give names with those quotes and escaping characters as  Input names. That's the first thing.

Comment: @ngen, in theory, yes, but PHP developers sometimes name the check boxes or radio buttons in a group `something[]`, in order for the server-side code to receive an array containing the values submitted for these elements.